# Convert normal variable to Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-services

I have this in my service:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
import { Response } from '@angular/http'
import { Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { AppSettings, HttpClient } from './shared';
import _ from "lodash";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    private currentTruckTrailer: any;
    private trucksTrailers: any;
    public truckTrailerModified$: ReplaySubject<any>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.truckTrailerModified$ = new ReplaySubject(1);

    }

    clearCache() {
        this.currentTruckTrailer = null;
        this.trucksTrailers = null;
    }

    login(username: string, password: string, clientID: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/User/Login`, { username: username, password: password, clientID: clientID }).map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
    }

    getTrailersAndTrucks(): Observable<any> {
        if (this.trucksTrailers) {
            return Observable.of(this.trucksTrailers);
        }
        else {
            return this.http.get(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/User/GetTrailersAndTrucks`).map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    this.trucksTrailers = response.json();
                    return this.trucksTrailers;
                }
                else {
                    return "FAILURE";
                }
            });
        }
    }

    saveTrailerAndTruck(truckID: string, trailerID: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/User/SaveTrailerAndTruck`, { truckID: truckID, trailerID: trailerID }).map((response: Response) => {

            var truck = _.find(this.trucksTrailers.Trucks, function (item: any) {
                return item.ID == truckID;
            });

            var trailer = _.find(this.trucksTrailers.Trailers, function (item: any) {
                return item.ID == trailerID;
            });

            this.currentTruckTrailer = { Truck: truck, Trailer: trailer };

            this.truckTrailerModified$.next(this.currentTruckTrailer);
            return response.json();
        });
    }

    getCurrentTruckAndTrailer() {
        if (this.currentTruckTrailer) {
            return Observable.of(this.currentTruckTrailer);
        }
        else {
            return this.http.get(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/User/GetCurrentTruckAndTrailer`).map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    this.currentTruckTrailer = response.json();
                    return this.currentTruckTrailer;
                }
                else {
                    return "FAILURE";
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly. What I want is when I modify the `this.currentTruckTrailer` inside `saveTrailerAndTruck` the subscribers should change their values automatically. At the moment I am using  public ReplaySubject `truckTrailerModified$: ReplaySubject<any>;` to broadcast the subscribe. Question is how do I turn the  `this.currentTruckTrailer` into Observable so listeners can directly subscribe upon it. What changes would I need to make inside `saveTrailerAndTruck` and `getCurrentTruckAndTrailer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `BehaviorSubject` ([documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md)):

first of all, you have to initialize it:

```
currentTruckTrailer:BehaviorSubject<any> = new behaviorSubject<any>();
```

When you want to store the next value of your data, you can use `next()`:

```
this.currentTruckTrailer.next({ Truck: truck, Trailer: trailer });
```

When you subscribe to this `Observable`, you'll receive the last stored value if one exists, and your subscriber will get called everytime you call `next()`.

**EDIT:**
Here is an example implementation in your service. Since I do'nt know the context and how you want to use this service, this is probably not the best implementation you can get. The goal of this example is to show you how to implement it.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Response} from '@angular/http'
import {Observable, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {AppSettings, HttpClient} from './shared';
import _ from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    private currentTruckTrailer: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>();
    private trucksTrailers: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        //First of all, we initialize the currentTruckTrailer with a value coming from http.
        this.http.get(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/User/GetCurrentTruckAndTrailer`)
            .subscribe((response: Response) => {
                this.currentTruckTrailer = new BehaviorSubject<any>(response.json());
            });

        //Same for truckTrailers.
        this.http.get(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/User/GetTrailersAndTrucks`)
            .subscribe((response: Response) => {
                this.trucksTrailers = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(response.json());
            });
    }

    login(username: string, password: string, clientID: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/User/Login`, {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            clientID: clientID
        }).map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
    }

    getTrailersAndTrucks(): Observable<any> {
        return this.trucksTrailers;
    }

    saveTrailerAndTruck(truckID: string, trailerID: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/User/SaveTrailerAndTruck`, {
            truckID: truckID,
            trailerID: trailerID
        }).do(() => {

            const truck = _.find(this.trucksTrailers.Trucks, function (item: any) {
                return item.ID == truckID;
            });

            const trailer = _.find(this.trucksTrailers.Trailers, function (item: any) {
                return item.ID == trailerID;
            });

            this.currentTruckTrailer.next({Truck: truck, Trailer: trailer});
        }).map(response => {
            return response.json();
        });
    }

    getCurrentTruckAndTrailer(): Observable<any> {
        return this.currentTruckTrailer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not follow how to use it. Could you please modify it in my service. I guess the methods to modify are **saveTrailerAndTruck** and **getCurrentTruckAndTrailer**

Comment: if I understand well your needs, your UserService has to act like a cache for trailersAndTrucks variable?

Comment: @TimLiberty I edited the answer, but if your need is a cache service, I can give you a better example I did for one of my projects on github.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure if it would work. How would I use this in my component? **this.currentTruckTrailer** is initialized inside the subscribe of http. So how would I subscribe on that since the http call is asynchronous. Yes I do need a cached service. So if you have a better example that too is fine I could choose that path - no issue.  But for my understanding could you also modify the example you posted here? Thank you :)

Comment: You can initialize the subjects directly in the fields, I edited the example.